# gnuplot lost the plot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm experimenting with evolutionary algorithms and I have written two text files that I cannot get the plot.  Based on the information on google, I think I have the format correct.

(generation-number) (tab) (best-fitness)

for example:

1   231

2   240

3   245
 ...

To plot this, I start gnuplot and I am greeted by the welcome screen.  I then type: plot 'ga.txt'

The cursor immediately returns and nothing is plotted.

I am using 64 bit Mint with Mate.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this problem is to install gnuplot-x11 and to set the terminal from 'unknown' to 'x11'.